# remove first comma in string using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

my string like that :

```
1  ,QCIM1J25836, QCIM1J27637
2  ,QCIM1J25836, QCIM1J27637, QCIM1J27638
```

I want to remove first comma only it means my output will be for

```
1  QCIM1J25836, QCIM1J27637
2  QCIM1J25836, QCIM1J27637, QCIM1J27638
```

may be in other will not be comma...so please tell me how can I update all data like that...

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Answer (score 3):

In *SQL-Server* you can do It in multiple ways.

You use `STUFF` in following:

```
SELECT col1, 
       STUFF(col2,1,1,'') as [Col Without First Comma]
FROM tbl
WHERE col2 LIKE ',%'
```

or you can use `RIGHT`

```
SELECT col1, 
       RIGHT(col2,LEN(col2)-1) as [Col Without First Comma]
FROM tbl
WHERE col2 LIKE ',%';
```

or you can use `SUBSTRING`

```
SELECT col1,
       SUBSTRING(col2, 2, 255) as [Col Without First Comma]
FROM tbl
WHERE col2 LIKE ',%';
```

---

**UPDATE**

As per your comment you can update in the same ways too:

Using `SUBSTRING`

```
UPDATE tbl
SET col2 = SUBSTRING(col2, 2, 255)
WHERE col2 LIKE ',%';
```

Or using `RIGHT`

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET col2 = RIGHT(col2,LEN(col2)-1) 
WHERE col2 LIKE ',%';
```

Or using `STUFF`

```
UPDATE tbl
SET col2 = STUFF(col2,1,1,'')
WHERE col2 LIKE ',%';
```

Comment: can I make update query for that ...I want to update data and remove first comma

Comment: @VipinSinghal and do not forget accept It as correct answer for future users If It helped for your. To do It you can mark `V` in top-left corner of answer.

Answer (score 3):

The following query should work:
It will update all the records in the column.

```
UPDATE table
SET col2 = CASE WHEN LEFT(col2 ,1) =',' THEN RIGHT(col2,LEN(col2)-1)
                    ELSE col2 END
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table
SET col2 =  case when charindex(',',col2,0) =1 then right(col2, len(col2)-1) else col2 end
```

Comment: This answer is more logical

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [LIB]
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[trimChar]
(
    @p_string  varchar(max),
    @p_char varchar(1)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
   declare @l_string varchar(max) = @p_string
   -- lets do the front
   while SUBSTRING(@l_string,1,1) = @p_char
   begin
      set @l_string = substring(@l_string,2,len(@l_string))
   end

   -- lets do the back
   set @l_string = reverse(@l_string)
   while SUBSTRING(@l_string,1,1) = @p_char
   begin
      set @l_string = substring(@l_string,2,len(@l_string))
   end
   set @l_string = reverse(@l_string)

   return @l_string

END
GO
```